# rails assets:precompile Yarn executable was not detected in the system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu, yarnpkg

I am using Linux 18 based on Ubunt 17.04.
When I run `rails assets:precompile` I get the following message `Yarn executable was not detected in the system`

When I follow the instruction for the installation like in this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45486362/rails-precompile-assets-yarn-executable-was-not-detected) or on the [Webpage](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#linux-tab), I install Yarn successfully, but rails keeps giving me the error

I notice that [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) has system packages for Linux Mint up to version `17.2` , I tried to do all the instruction for the `Yarn` page and install manually `node.js` which was already installed in my system.

The message is not really explanatory of the problem. If I run `yarn --help` it works and my `yarn --version` is `0.22`

This is my Linux Mint system

```
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18
DISTRIB_CODENAME=sarah
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 18 Sarah"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
cat: /etc/upstream-release: Is a directory
```

---

Update

This is the output of my echo `$PATH` in the terminal `/opt/yarn-0.22/bin`, but when I go to that path, there is no folder `/opt/yarn-0.22` so I need to understand where it was installed and configure correctly the `PATH SETUP`

```
Path Setup

If you chose manual installation, the following steps will add Yarn to path variable and run it from anywhere.

Note: your profile may be in your .profile, .bash_profile, .bashrc, .zshrc, etc.

Add this to your profile: export PATH="$PATH:/opt/yarn-[version]/bin" (the path may vary depending on where you extracted Yarn to)
In the terminal, log in and log out for the changes to take effect
To have access to Yarn’s executables globally, you will need to set up the PATH environment variable in your terminal. To do this, add export PATH="$PATH:`yarn global bin`" to your profile.
```

Thanks a lot 
Best Regards
Fabrizio Bertoglio

Comment: do you have yarn cli install as global package?

Comment: @uzaif hi, you are right. This is the output of my `echo $PATH` in the terminal `/opt/yarn-0.22/bin`, but when I go to that path, there is no folder `/opt/yarn-0.22` so I need to understand where it was installed and configure correctly the `PATH SETUP`

Comment: It's installed in global node_module directory which is located under home

Comment: @uzaif you have linux mint? I have the executable file in `/usr/bin` and I can run yarn with `/usr/bin/yarn` or `yarn`.. but probably when `rbenv` runs `yarn` command, it just does not work. I did include in my bash profile `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin/yarn"`

In Linux `/` is the root directory, `/home/<username/` is the user directory. Yarn is installed in the root directory and to  be executed with the `yarn` command I should include in my `$PATH` variable export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin/yarn"

Comment: Can you tell me are you able to get yarn cli working properly

Comment: @uzaif looks like the `yarn cli` is not working. when I run `yarn initi` I get `ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'init'`

Comment: Did you install it via npm?

Comment: @uzaif no as by instruction on their page. `curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list` and then `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn`

I am reading https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1194

Comment: Can you install via npm like this `npm install yarn -g`

Comment: Hi @uzaif You are right again. I run `sudo npm install yarn -g` then try again `rails assets:precompile` and now I have this output `yarn install v0.27.5
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 0.40s.` I wonder what is this? I am used to the normal `rails assets:precompile` .. but still it is fixed so .. please post your answer and I will accept it . thanks .. Fabrizio

Comment: It's because I think you are you using webpacker or creat-react-app cli which requires to install front-end dependency

Comment: @uzaif not using webpacker or create-react-app ... I am just using rails, don't know why this `yarn` came out.. I am using some jquery plugin... can't really determine the real issue right now. this solution should be ok for a while.. you can post your answer i will accept it thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

yarn is node package manager [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/)

you have to install it as here instrauction [installation guide](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install)
 If you have node and npm  you can install it 
 via

> `npm install yarn -g`

---

> If you dont have `npm` in your machine go to  [this link](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and install `node` which will also install `npm`

---

> If you want to manage multiple version node like `RVM` then you need to checkout [this link](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)