# 'yarn execetable was not detected in system'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, yarnpkg

I'm at my wit's end. I'm trying to push a new rails 5 application to heroku, and i keep getting the error message "`yarn executable was not detected in system`" whenever the `rake assets:precompile` starts.

I have followed all of the instructions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45498313/rails-assetsprecompile-yarn-executable-was-not-detected-in-the-system?noredirect=1#comment77964282_45498313) post, the installation instructions from the [yarn site](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#debian-stable), and even tried the solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45486362/rails-precompile-assets-yarn-executable-was-not-detected) post.

Every time that I run `yarn --version` from the command line, it looks as if it's installed perfectly fine, and I get the following result: `1.7.0`

If anybody else can recommend something else to try, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!